# Japanese badge notification

Tags: bug, badges, notifications, internationalization

Everywhere, except Meta, badge notification is in... Japanese

> [image]

Is it expected behaviour?

Comment: Related: [Portuguese notification on SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274512/247702)